# Add labels to barplot with stat=summary

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, bar-chart

I have a problem that was probaly already asked many times. However, I could not find any solution that helped me. I would like to have the values of the individual bars displayed in the center of each bar.
My code is following

```
  geom_bar(aes(x=Fläche, y=Bestäuberarten, fill=Fläche), 
           stat = "summary", fun = "mean")+
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("Brachfläche" = "#E74C3C", "Gestaltete Natur" = "#DAF7A6", "Trockenrasen" = "#F7DC6F"))+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        text = element_text(size=12), legend.position="none", legend.title = element_blank())+
  labs(x =element_blank(), y = "Ø-Anzahl Bestäuber")
```

Would  be happy about any help. I guess it has something to do with my aes and the stat="summary" part, but I tried many solutions but nothing worked.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 'computed variables' documented in every `stat_*()` function that you can use in combination with `after_stat()` or `stage()` to access these. In the example below, we're `stage()`ing to let the y-value initially be `mpg`, but halving it after the summary has been computed. Likewise, we're using `after_stat()` for the label to be the summarised y-value.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "summary", fun = "mean") +
  geom_text(stat = "summary", fun = "mean",
            aes(y = stage(mpg, after_stat = y / 2),
                label = after_stat(y)))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-07-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

If you're finding that you're using the same statistic in a bunch of layers, it might be more convenient to precompute the statistic.